# iPad how to make the side bar disappear temporarily?

Tags: sidebar

How to make the sidebar disappear temporarily?
I am trying to play a game on my iPad but the sidebar is in the way.  I don’t want to delete the sidebar permanently because I use it quite often during the day.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by sidebar?  Do you mean the Slide Over multitasking feature?

Comment: Perhaps [edit]ing with a screenshot including the 'sidebar' you want to hide might be helpful?